# How to JavaInputDStream JSON to ElasticSearch JAVA

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

hi guys I'm working with kafka > spark streaming > Elasticsearch.
but i dont make spark streaming JavaInputDStream JSON to elasticsearch.

My Code :

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("Streaming")
            .setMaster("local")
            .set("es.nodes","localhost:9200")
            .set("es.index.auto.create","true");
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(5000));
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "exastax");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("loglar");
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    streamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
            );

    JavaPairDStream<String, String> finisStream = stream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>("", record.value()));
    finisStream.print();
    JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(finisStream,"spark/docs");
    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();


}
```

JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(finisStream,"spark/docs"); >> finisStream isn't working because it's not JavaDStream.
How to convert JavaDStream ?

Answer (score 1):

`JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs` works with `JavaDStream`

`JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveToEsWithMeta` works with `JavaPairDStream`

To fix your code:

```
JavaDStream<String> finisStream = stream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
        return stringStringTuple2._2();
    }
});

JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(finisStream,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

thnx a lot for answer! but i solved this code :

```
 JavaDStream<String> stream1 = stream.map(
                new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> r) {
                        return r.value();
                    }
                }
        );
           JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(stream1,"spark/docs");
```